# Azure deploy service app with docker compose

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a simple application with Docker Composer (Preview) on Azure. I have 2 images, one for back-end API and the other for front-end.

```
version: "3"
services: 
  backend: 
    image: spring-backend
    ports:
      - '8080:8080' 
  angular: 
    image: angular 
    container_name: angular
```

But when I see the log, it is binding in the wrong port and the application does not work properly.

```
2023-04-12T04:47:06.271Z INFO - docker run -d -p 7413:8080 --name solution_test_7edf902b -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=test-example-solution -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=test-example-solution.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=b08b793703ed90c29d190499db3bc194822d9b232329810c8844678e66822c18 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False spring-backend
```

Every time that I restart the service or change the deployment, it seems that I choose a random port to bind.

Comment: What is the framework and version of your Application?

Comment: In your `docker-compose.yml` file , add PORT with 80 Within the angular section and check once.

Comment: I am using a spring boot made with Java as backend and an angular application as front. I tried add a PORT within the angular section too, but it still cause the same problem

Comment: @OEstudante Try configuring your app service with the port number in which your application is running. You can configure `Websites_Port: 8080` the port number by adding application settings under configuration in Azure portal.

Comment: It's still show a random port in the log when I run `docker run -d -p <random>:8080`

Answer (score 0):

> It's still show a random port in the log when I run `docker run -d -p <random>:8080`

AFAIK, when we run the command `docker run -d -p <random>:8080`, Docker maps the container's port 8080 to a random port on the host machine to avoid port conflicts when multiple containers are running on the same host.
I was also getting the random port, but I could deploy and run the application successfully.

- Use the `docker ps` command to see the mapping between the container's port and the host's port.

In your case, you can try adding `WEBSITES_PORT:8080` as an application setting under configuration section in your App Service and also check if the solutions provided in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168746/container-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-on-port-8080?page=1#answers) helps you to fix the issue.
[image]

I have reproduced and checked the same in my environment by creating a sample spring boot application.
Created `docker-compose.yml` using command `nano docker-compose.yml` with below script:
[image]
using docker-compose, I have created a docker-compose.yml file app service using below command:

```
az webapp create --resource-group <Resource_Group_Name> --plan <App_Service_Plan> --name <App_name> --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file <yml_file_name>
```

[image]

- Deployed my container using `docker-compose` with the port configuration 8080.

[image]
**Result:**
Application deployed and running successfully.
[image]